# Subsetting a list based on a conditions of sublists in R?

Tags: r, list, subset

I am hoping to get some pointers on how to implement this with the apply family of functions. I have a list (listbin)and want to subset using contents in the sublist (x and Ineligible) of my list.

The structure of the list is shown below:

```
[[1]]
[[1]]$x
[1] "2015-01-12"

[[1]]$rslts
factor(0)
Levels: PD

[[1]]$Ineligible
[1] 0

[[2]]$x
[[1]]$rslts
factor(0)
Levels: 0 1 A CR D E IS PD PR SD

[[1]]$Ineligible
[1] 0

...
```

For my purposes, this code works perfectly for 1, 2 and 3 of my sublists, but I am looking for an elegant way to do this throughout my sublists.

```
'[['(listbin, 1)$x [which( '[['(listbin, 1)$Ineligible==0 ) ]
'[['(listbin, 2)$x [which( '[['(listbin, 2)$Ineligible==0 ) ]
'[['(listbin, 3)$x [which( '[['(listbin, 3)$Ineligible==0 ) ]
```

Comment: can you give an example of your `listbin`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We could create a function and then loop over the index and extract the components

```
f1 <- function(lst1, i, nm1, nm2){
    '[['(lst1, i)[[nm1]] [which( '[['(lst1, i)[[nm2]]==0 ) ]  
   }

lapply(1:3, function(i) f1(listbin, i = i, 'x', 'Ineligible'))
```

Comment: Thanks - this works. One question: how the length of the list (1:n) be dynamically be returned for use in the lapply statement?

Comment: @user1916067 If `n` is the argument, then you can have `lappy(seq_len(n), ` if that is what you meant